# How to write data to an xml file

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I want to store data (preferences) into an xml file , but I can't achieve it. I took a look at appledeveloper web but it seems not clear to me .
I want to store the xml file on disk . My preferences that I created are some checkboxes (ih the user cheks the login box for example and I add this preference login to the xml file) , radio group, textfields
can you give me a good tutorial or an example that shows that please?

Comment: Is plist-flavour XML good enough?

Comment: "I can't achieve it" - What exactly can't you achieve?

Comment: I mean I can't create the xml file with data. I have to get preferences data and store them in an xml file

Comment: You should provide information like: How your preferences are currently stored. What you have tried? What your output should look like. Where do you plan to store this information on disk?

Comment: Yes James, I want to store the xml file on disk . My preferences are some checkboxes (ih the user cheks the login box for example i add this preference login to the xml file) , radio group, textfields.

Comment: Add this information to your question.. People aren't going to trawl through comments to get information

Comment: You really should store it as NSUserDefaults. That's the way Apple wanted to have it for. Read @DrummerB's answer

Comment: what about storing data in nsdictionnary or ns array and then write them to the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You usually store preferences using the [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Option1" forKey:@"PreferenceName1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"PreferenceName2"];
```

And then read like this:

```
NSString *pref1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PreferenceName1"];
BOOL pref2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PreferenceName2"];
```

Comment: thanks can you detail more please . I want when the user checks the log box for example add this to the xml file

Comment: You said you want to save preferences right? You usually do this with NSUserDefaults. Take a look at the documentation how it works. It will write your preferences in a plist formatted xml file. But you don't have to deal with that. You just use the methods supplied by NSUserDefaults.

Comment: ok thanks , i want to save them in a xml file created by me and stored on disk

Comment: what about storing data in nsdictionnary or ns array and then write them to the xml file?

Comment: and can you send me a link of documentation

Comment: I linked the documentation in my answer. And what's wrong with what I suggested? You don't seem to like it.

Comment: ah ok thznks I didn't seen it